# Improve query that count and join many tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count

My (simplified) database schema:
[image]

Each operation have a set of hostname which can generate an error. Each hostname is accepted from a list of domains and each domain is associated to an organization (through a phase of acceptance).

I'd like to have a result set like:

```
+----+--------------------+--------------+----------------+--------------+
| id | organization_count | domain_count | hostname_count | errors_count |
+----+--------------------+--------------+----------------+--------------+
| 79 |                  1 |            1 |              4 |            4 |
| 78 |                  1 |            4 |             16 |         NULL |
| 77 |                  1 |            4 |             16 |           16 |
| 76 |                  1 |            4 |             16 |         NULL |
+----+--------------------+--------------+----------------+--------------+
```

My query is:

```
SELECT operation.id,
       tally_o.organization_count,
       tally_d.domain_count,
       tally_h.hostname_count,
       tally_h.errors_count
FROM   operation
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT hostname_operation.operation_id,
                         COUNT(*) AS hostname_count,
                         errors.errors_count
                  FROM   hostname_operation
                         LEFT JOIN (SELECT operation_id,
                                           COUNT(*) AS errors_count
                                    FROM   hostname_operation
                                    WHERE  error_id IS NOT NULL
                                    GROUP  BY operation_id) AS errors
                                ON hostname_operation.operation_id =
                                   errors.operation_id
                  GROUP  BY operation_id) AS tally_h
              ON operation.id = tally_h.operation_id
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT hostname_operation.operation_id,
                         COUNT(DISTINCT domain.id) AS domain_count
                  FROM   domain
                         JOIN accepted
                           ON domain.id = accepted.domain_id
                         JOIN hostname
                           ON accepted.id = hostname.accepted_id
                         JOIN hostname_operation
                           ON hostname.id = hostname_operation.hostname_id
                  GROUP  BY hostname_operation.operation_id) AS tally_d
              ON operation.id = tally_d.operation_id
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT hostname_operation.operation_id,
                         COUNT(DISTINCT organization.id) AS organization_count
                  FROM   organization
                         JOIN accepted
                           ON organization.id = accepted.organization_id
                         JOIN hostname
                           ON accepted.id = hostname.accepted_id
                         JOIN hostname_operation
                           ON hostname.id = hostname_operation.hostname_id
                  GROUP  BY hostname_operation.operation_id) AS tally_o
              ON operation.id = tally_o.operation_id
ORDER  BY operation.id DESC
LIMIT  0, 4;
```

I'm using MySQL 5.5. Even though the query is fast (~0,4s), the problem is that the [`EXPLAIN`](http://pastebin.com/pR8BdRt4) shows for each `...LEFT JOIN (SELECT...` the db isn't using any index. Also softwares like mysqltuner show that I'm doing a lot of query without index.

How can I improve the query? `SUM + GROUP BY` could be a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good news are that your query can be rewritten without subqueries, using only 3 left joins and single group by.

**edited:**

```
select o.id,
  count(distinct a.organization_id) organization_count,
  count(distinct a.domain_id) domain_count,
  count(ho.hostname_id) hostname_count,
  count(ho.error_id) errors_count
from operation o 
  left outer join hostname_operation ho on o.id=ho.operation_id
  left join hostname h on h.id=ho.hostname_id
  left join accepted a on a.id=h.accepted_id
group by o.id
order by o.id
```

You gave no information about indices in your database, so it is impossible to make conclusion about index usage. I only can suggest that if database have proper indices for all primary and foreign keys - it will be sufficient for efficient execution of the query given above.

Comment: And if you are not interested in listing `operation_id`s with zero hostname_count - table `operation` can be completely removed from the join, making query very simple.

Comment: All the joins should be `LEFT` joins.

Comment: @ypercube I think no - because according to UML specs data model picture given means that every `hostname_operation` tuple refers _exactly one_ `hostname` tuple and every `hostname` tuple refers _exactly one_ `accepted` tuple. Am I not right?

Comment: That is right but the last two `ON` condition (say the `on h.id=ho.hostname_id`) can be true only when the `ho.hostname_id` is not null. So by having the last two joins as `INNER` joins, you are essentially cancelling the first `LEFT` join as well (making it an inner join.)

Comment: If that is right - then `ho.hostname_id` _can not be null_, because it would mean `hostname_operation` without corresponding `hostname`, what violates the model depicted. So inner joins do not cancel left join in this concrete model.

Comment: Whether `hostname_operation.hostname_id` is nullable or not is irrelevant. `ho.hostname_id` is a column in the query that can have Nulls anyway (because of the `operation o left outer join hostname_operation ho`.) Any outer join can **produce** Nulls in the results. And these results will be used in the following join, to `hostname`.

Comment: When you start with `outer join` you have to follow it through or use parentheses to specify order of joins. `hostname` and `accepted` are joined to `hostname_operation`; if there is no `hostname_operation` there cannot be corresponding row in other tables. `Inner join` will therefore remove `operation` without `hostname_operation`, effectively canceling `left join`.

Comment: Thanks @all.
@mas.morozov: all the indexes are in the UML. I removed all the other non-indexed field. Ids are PK and FKs are indexed too. Since I use MySQL can I replace `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with just `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: @Luca Yes, you can. `OUTER` is just an optional keyword. And you seem to have all the right indices in right places. If you (maybe) still get the table scan warnings - this is because the query is unbounded (does not have any where-conditions at all) - so the most tables are read through in any way.